reading a "TrueType font (font/ttf)" file
I am trying to read a ttf file and I need some special tools to do it. for example I used
from lenstools.simulations import Gadget2SnapshotDE , Gadget2Snapshot
and then
snap = Gadget2Snapshot.open('my_ttf_file')
when I used
snap.getID()
half of the ids were 0. how do I fix this?
from lenstools.simulations import Gadget2Snapshot
from astropy.units import Mpc, m, s

snap = Gadget2Snapshot.open('lcdmML_snap000_cdm')
ids_1 = snap.getID()
ids_1


the result is:
array([       0,        0,        7, ...,        0, 16646125,        0]
but there is many duplicated zeroes in the array and there should not be. because every id is different.

Why the astropy import? Gadget2Snapshot also doesn't seem to be the right tool, just going by its name.
